# Elements of $\sigma(\mathcal A \cup \{C\})$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal A)$ be a measurable space.

If $C$ is a subspace of $X$, why are the elements of $\sigma(\mathcal A \cup \{C\})$ of the form: $(A_1 \cap C) \cup (A_2 \cap C^c)$, with $A_1, A_2 \in \mathcal A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. This new class contains $C$: $C=(X\cap C)\cup (\emptyset \cap C^{c})$. It contains each member $A$ of $\mathcal A$: $A=(A\cap C)\cup (A \cap C^{c})$. It is enough to verify that this class is a sigma algebra. It is easy to see that it is closed under countable unions and intersections. Note that $(A\cap C)^{c}=(X \cap C^{c}) \cup (C\cap A^{c})$. The rest should be clear now.